# respond_to? returns false when self can call the method, and super seems to ignore changes to inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm confused by the results of my debugger outputs. `url_standardizers` does what I think it will. But then I don't get why `self` wont respond to the method added by the module or why the attribute `path` isn't saving with the added trailing slash,

```
module Standardizers

  def url_standardizers(url_fragment)
    url_fragment = url_fragment.strip
    url_fragment << "/" if url_fragment !~ /\/\z/
    url_fragment.downcase
  end

  module_function :url_standardizers
  ...
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include Standardizers

   17:   def path=(pathname)
   18:     byebug
=> 19:     super(url_standardizers(pathname))
   20:   end
   21: 

(byebug) url_standardizers(pathname)
"fewew/"
(byebug) self.respond_to? :url_standardizers
false
(byebug) c
=> "fewew"
```

Comment: what is `c`? But yes, interesting...

Comment: `module_function` creates a _private_ instance method and `respond_to?` doesn't include private methods by default.

Comment: @Stefan: damn, this got me again :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `module_function` creates a private instance method (according to [the documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/module_function)), consider using `private_method_defined?` instead:

```
(byebug) self.respond_to? :url_standardizers
false

(byebug) self.class.private_method_defined? :url_standardizers
true
```

As Stefan mentions in the comments, `respond_to?` takes an [optional second argument](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/respond_to%3F) that you can use to get private methods as well:

```
(byebug) self.respond_to?(:url_standardizers, true)
true
```

Comment: either that or `respond_to?(:url_standardizers, true)`